# how do i conceal my phpmyadmin from people visiting my site

Tags: centos

how do I move phpmyadmin away from the root url?

for example instead of typing: mysite.com/phpmyadmin

i want it to be more secure by making it a few directories down ?

or is there another way of hiding  phpmyadmin?

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you put authentication in place instead of hiding it?  You know, the whole security-by-obscurity-is-no-security thing?

Comment: i alreayd have authentication just want it to be harder to access

Comment: Don't install it on a public server, it has no place there.

Comment: found the answer here so thanks for that downvote...hope this helps others http://www.thetechrepo.com/main-articles/488

Comment: Please don't use phpMyAdmin on a production system. That's really an easy way to get your system owned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd highly recommend you lock PHPMyAdmin down to one IP address, while blocking everything else. This way, you -do not- need to worry about security. If your computer gets hacked, they might have access, so I'd recommend still having a good secure password to login. :)

If you want the perfect security system of all, don't use PHPMyAdmin and use MySQL through an app like Sequel Pro (on the Mac) and go through a SSH tunnel with a certificate. That would be very hard to get through... and personally, this is what I do. :)